# SnowSQL: Cache credentials

Tags: configuration, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, credentials

I have to use SSO to authenticate, which I do via a browser. I run queries with:

```
$ snowsql -a <ACCOUNT> -u <USERNAME> -r <ROLE> --authenticator externalbrowser -f foo.sql
```

However, this requires me to do the annoying browser authentication process every time. I know that account/user/role can be put in the config, those are not the problem since I often change all three - but I'd like to avoid having to open/close the browser for SSO auth every time I run a query.

Is there a way to make SnowSQL cache the credentials, so that on repeated runs like this, I don't have to reauthenticate?

Comment: Did you check the documentation?  You could put all of that information into a config file and never need the annoying authentication process ever again.  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowsql-config.html#connection-parameters-section

Comment: If your question is about the use of the external browser authentication then I don’t believe there is a way round this. Instead you should consider using key-pair authentication when using the CLI

Comment: @MikeWalton What exactly would I put in the config? From what I can tell at best I can avoid having to type in the CLI args but I would still have to open the browser to authenticate.

Comment: @NickW Yes, my question is about using browser authentication, as I explained in the question text. If the answer is no, feel free to leave an answer. Can key pair auth be set up by the user, or is it something that the Snowflake account admin must enable?

Comment: @Dommondke I missed the externalbrowser in your command and your description didn't mention it.  Sorry about that.  Config would be for either key-pair or user/password storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Key pair authentication is documented here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/key-pair-auth.html

In my view it is the best solution when using the CLI and you want the authorisation steps to be as minimal as possible